# Get a part of a line with the matching string from a paragraph using perl grep

Tags: regex, perl, grep

I have an array ,the contents of which is given below:

```
print Dumper(\@jsession);

$VAR1 = [
'<html><body><form name = \'form\' id=\'form\' method = \'POST\' action =        \'/mySite.jsp\'><input type = hidden name = \'phpSessionID\' value =   \'GZbtXhI9JiQ**\'><input type = hidden name = \'LoggedUserName\' value =  \'MyName\'><!--input type = submit name = \'button\' value ='\'goAhead\'--></form>    <script language = \'JavaScript\'> document.getElementById(\'form\').submit();</script>  </body></html>
];
```

My aim is to get the phpSessionID value in a variable say $session,i.e

```
$session=GZbtXhI9JiQ**;
```

I have  to do this using Perl grep. I tried the following though its not much to go on,

```
$session=grep(/^<.*phpSessionID.*>$/,@jsession);
```

Iam new to RegEx and am struggling to get it right.

Comment: That Perl code doesn't compile so it can't be the output of `Data::Dumper`. The string has no closing quote at the end, and there is `value ='\'goAhead\'` in the middle which ends the string prematurely.

Comment: that section is coomented out <!--input type = submit name = \'button\' value ='\'goAhead\'-->,i have not given the code that generates the @jsession array

Comment: HTML comments don't affect Perl - your code doesn't compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want the `value` attribute from the `input` element that has a `name` attribute of `phpSessionID`. This one.

```
<input type = hidden name = 'phpSessionID' value =   'GZbtXhI9JiQ**'>
```

You should parse your HTML using a module intended for the job, such as [`HTML::TreeBuilder`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aTreeBuilder).  It cannot be done reliably using a regular expression because there is so much variation in the possible formats of the element.

Answer (score 0):

Borodin's advice to use [HTML::TreeBuilder](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML%3a%3aTreeBuilder) or some other parsing module is definitely the way to go.

Because I haven't used that module in a while, I decided to go ahead and implement what he suggested using the html that you provided.  I've reformatted the html slightly just to make it easier to read, but that wouldn't effect the functioning of this code:

```
use HTML::TreeBuilder;

use strict;
use warnings;

my $root = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content(<DATA>);

if (my $element = $root->look_down('_tag' => 'input', 'name' => 'phpSessionID')) {
    print "Value is " . $element->attr('value') . "\n";
} else {
    warn "phpSessionID not found";
}

__DATA__
<html>
<body>
<form name = 'form' id='form' method = 'POST' action =        '/mySite.jsp'>
<input type = hidden name = 'phpSessionID' value =   'GZbtXhI9JiQ**'>
<input type = hidden name = 'LoggedUserName' value =  'MyName'>
<!--input type = submit name = 'button' value =''goAhead'-->
</form>    
<script language = 'JavaScript'>
document.getElementById('form').submit();
</script>
</body></html>
```

Outputs

```
Value is GZbtXhI9JiQ**
```